# How to expand the borders, beside Outposts and Colony-ships in Stellaris

Tags: stellaris

Beside the obvious - building Outposts and Colony-ships, what other options are there to expand the borders?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of [technologies](http://www.stellariswiki.com/Technology) you can research that increase the size of the borders around your outposts and colony ships, including

- Galactic Ambitions
- Manifest Destiny
- Propaganda Transmissions (Repeatable)

The [Stellaris Wiki entry on borders](http://www.stellariswiki.com/Empire#Borders) also says that:

> Border spread appears to work volumetrically. That is, as the empire becomes more dense and grows, its borders also appear to spill outward. Removing colonies or frontier outposts from within the empire's well-established borders may affect the outer border unpredictably.

So building additional colonies and outposts in your empire's interior can increase your borders at the fringes.

If you're expanding your empire via frontier outposts, it's worth noting that

> Outposts controlled by sectors do not cost Influence to maintain.

Comment: "Outposts controlled by sectors do not cost Influence to maintain." - That's GREAT to know!!

Comment: Unfortunately, when you create an outpost and an observation station, and hand over this outpost to a sector, you can't control the setting of the station anymore (it seems the sector never changes it, though).

Comment: @GuntramBlohm That's true. You can take the system back out of the sector to change the setting, which costs some influence. Less than you've saved by not maintaining the observation post. I can confirm that the observation post will finish if you've put it on either advancement or infiltration, even when not under your control.

Comment: "Outposts controlled by sectors do not cost Influence to maintain." - that appears not to be true anymore.