# Does the border growth depend on a parameter in the game of Stellaris?

Tags: stellaris

Do they naturally grow slowly? Are they affected by influence or other parameters?

Comment: related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/265574/108003

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far I can determine border grow depends on population number on a planet.

IE If there is a 10 size planet then it will have border range corresponding to 10 population. Mind you that is just baseline border growth. 25 size is the highest you can go so you will get most influence from those.

I notice that border grow correspond with how many population you have on planets.

There are technologies that will boost how much range your border grow.

You can also build frontier outpost to expand in a certain direction but it has a draw back. Very tiny border grow and upkeep of one influence point a month.

Comment: I was under the impression that the borders grew constantly, but maybe not. You can also research technologies to increase your border range, which makes a big difference.

Comment: It is most likely your own planet's population growth that you are observing.

Comment: Mmm, does population affect the border?

Comment: It is fairly easy to notice if you watch your own border relative to your single homeworld's border when you gain a population. You can pick traits that increase population growth so you don't have to wait so long. Then compare that to what size it was before. You can also purge your own population and compare the border size before and after.

Comment: After playing some more and watching more carefully, I think you're probably right that it only goes up when your population increases.